# Restangular - Make POST request on JavaScript object call OPTIONS and Request Payload is empty

Tags: javascript, angularjs, restangular

I try to make a POST request on the /login url with a JS object as payload, here is the code below.
The problem is that I have **two** network calls, first one is an 'OPTIONS', second one is the POST.

I do **not** want the OPTIONS call to be made, I only want the POST call.

Thanks for your help !

```
var loginData = Restangular.one('login');
loginData.username = 'username@email.com';
loginData.password = 'password';
return loginData.post().then(function(user) {
  console.log(user.username, user.email);
});
```

Comment: you're right, domains are not the same, it explains the OPTIONS call (pre-flight).
Thanks !

The problem now is that I do not see the Request Payload data sent in the POST request. With a straight $http of course it works well, but with Restangular it does not.

Comment: thanks, i found the issue, not related to CORS but because I had an addRequestInterceptor who does not return the data...

Answer (score 1):

The problem was in the function addFullRequestInterceptor, I was not returning the element data.

```
Restangular.addFullRequestInterceptor(function(element, operation, what, url, headers, params, httpConfig) {

  //some logic here...

  //originally, the return below was not there... It is mandatory, if nothing is returned in that function, any POST or PUT request won't have any payload data.
  return {
    element: element,
    headers: headers,
    params: params,
    httpConfig: httpConfig
  };
});
```